# Are Roslyn's code generation APIs immutable?

Tags: .net, roslyn

I'm starting to experiment with Roslyn to do a bit of code generation. I've noticed when I call `.Add...` on a syntax object, the original object I'm calling on is not mutated. Is that the way Roslyn was designed? Is there a way to make it mutable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, syntax trees are immutable. Some original design discussion from the Roslyn team are here on immutability:

‪‬https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/Bliki/wiki/Roslyn-Immutable-Trees

A few points are concurrency and thread safety, and being able to de-duplicate without needing to implement something like copy-on-write.

I'm not aware of a way to make them mutable.